# Don't reset attribute after form submition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've the code which submits the `form#statisticForm`. In the script I have written I substitute `src`, which is located inside the `span` element:

```
<form id="statisticForm">
    <input type="hidden id="statisticForm:fsp" />
    <span id = "span1" class="a-custom-sorting">
        <img src="img.jpg"/>
    </span>
    <!--Another such span elements -->
    <span id = "span123" class="a-custom-sorting">
        <img src="img.jpg"/>
    </span>
</form>
```

Script:

```
jQuery('.a-custom-sorting').click(function() {
    var submitField = document.getElementById("statisticForm:fsp");
    var img = jQuery(this).find("img");
    var new_src;
    switch (img.attr("src")) {
        case "img.jpg":
        case "second_clicked_img.jpg":
            new_src = "img1.jpg";
            break;
        case "first_clicked_img.jpg":
            new_src = "img2.jpg";
            break;
    }
    img.attr("src", new_src);
    submitField.value = this.id;
    document.getElementById("statisticForm").submit();
});
```

But after the form submition using the script above, `src` attribure of the `img` tag inside the `span` element I've clicked become equals to `img.jpg`. But I want that after form submission, `src` attribute doesn't change it value. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the page after the submit, you lost your switch in .click() and the DOM reload the default attributes.
You can make form with ajax and make change at callback, or set a variable after the refresh, and set the new attribute on document ready.